# Como obter o atributo "d" atualizado de um path SVG escalonado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte código pelo qual pego o conteúdo do atributo "d" de um `<path>` SVG, porém, preciso das coordenadas atualizadas depois de usar `scale` para aumentar o tamanho do desenho, porque quando solicito isso de aumentar ou diminuir a escala, tenho os mesmos valores das coordenadas iniciais.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
 .xxx {
  color:blue;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg>
 <path id="xxx" d="M100,10 L150,10 L150,60"
    style="stroke: #6666ff; stroke-width: 1px; fill: none;
            marker-start: url(#markerCircle);
            marker-end: url(#markerArrow);"
        />

</svg>
 
 <script>
 console.log(document.getElementById('xxx').getAttribute('d'));
 document.getElementById('xxx').style.transform='scale(2)';
 console.log(document.getElementById('xxx').getAttribute('d'));
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguma dica!

Comment: Cara não sei exatamente a aplicação ai, mas o interessante seria o SVG ter um viewbox, e o `d` começar no `0,0` desse viewbox, a partir dai vc faz o scale() do SVG como um todo

Comment: hugo, desculpe a demora. É que do jeito que vc sugeriu não  serve pois o `d`precisa ter liberdade para ser posicionado em qualquer posição  da tela. Não  existe uma função que guarde as coordenadas do `<path>` no momento em que ele é escalonado?

Comment: Ai não sei dizer, mas talvez vc possa os colocando um svg por cima do outro todos com 100% da altura e largura do elemento que estão sobrepondo, mas não sei se isso te ajudaria em algo, vc pode tb travar o transform-oringe no top left por exemplo pra tentar manter o x y de inicio fixo em um lugar

Comment: hugo, quando falei se existe uma função que guarde as coordenadas do `<path>`quando escalonado, eu quis dizer do novo valor das coordenadas, pois eu quero poder ter acesso às coordenadas da posição do desenho na tela, depois de um `scale`, entendeu? Ou seja, quando eu  tenho: `<path id="xxx" d="M100,10 L150,10 L150,60"` e uso `scale(5)`, por exemplo, eu quero as coordenadas do desenho já no novo tamanho. E o porém é que no DOM, o valor de `d`continua o inicial.